# (Concept) Creating a server communicating program with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, server

So let's say I want to create a simple ***2d iOS game in Swift*** that people can play with others over the internet. People are blocks that simply move around, and can chat with text to each other. Creating a single player version of this is no issue.

1. I'd need a server that can communicate with the app.
2. I'd need the app to be able to communicate with the server.
3. Either player can initiate an action that requires delivering information to the other side, in a reasonbly quick timeframe (IM-type latency, not email-type latency).

**First question:** Would I have to use OS X Server? Or is it possible to use a linux-based server (Which I have much experience with).

**Second question:**
Lets say user1 pressed the move up button.
What line of code would send this info to the server?
How would the server send this information back to user1 and to the other users?

If anyone can supply me all the information above I would be incredibly grateful. If I miss-tagged anything, or something needs clarification, just comment below and I will fix it asap.

Thanks guys!

Comment: These are vast question with virtually infinite possible answers. I recommend you do some online research and come back to Stack Overflow when you have much more specific questions like: "I am using NSURLConnection to send a request to my server but blah is happening". However, to get you on the right track: the language/tech you use on a server is completely independent of the language/tech you use on device as long as the common thread is an internet protocol like HTTP.